# How to upload image from Android application to a webserver into a specific folder

Tags: php, android, file-upload

How to move an image from android to specified folder on a web server

This is my android code

```
package com.example.bitmaptest;

import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Base64;
import android.util.Log;

public class Upload extends Activity {
InputStream is;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    Bitmap bitmapOrg=BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.a1);
    ByteArrayOutputStream bao = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bitmapOrg.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, bao);
    byte[] ba = bao.toByteArray();
    String ba1 = Base64.encodeToString(ba, 0);
    ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("image", ba1));

    try {

        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(
                "http://0.0.0.7:80/android/base.php");
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        is = entity.getContent();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection " + e.toString());
    }

}
}
```

and this is my php script

```
$uploadedFile = $_FILES['image']['name'];

$uploadedType = $_FILES['image']['type'];

$temp = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];

$error = $_FILES['image']['error'];

if ($error > 0) {
die("File could not be uploaded. $error");
}
else {
    move_uploaded_file($temp, "images/".$uploadedFile);
    echo "Upload Complete. ".$uploadedType;
}
```

When I send in android, httppost works, it shows in wireshark but the file is empty. There is no image.

Comment: The main reason for your code not working is, that you didn't set the content-type of the post-request to 'multipart/form-data'. See the answer of Nirav Ranpara below, that should help you.

Comment: so base64 is not working?base64 success when the image save in root. not a specified folder. when i move the specified folder theres no image, why multipart?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

doFileUpload Function :

```
private void doFileUpload(){
    HttpURLConnection conn = null;
    DataOutputStream dos = null;
    DataInputStream inStream = null; 
    String exsistingFileName = "/sdcard/six.3gp";
    // Is this the place are you doing something wrong.
    String lineEnd = "\r\n";
    String twoHyphens = "--";
    String boundary =  "*****";
    int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
    byte[] buffer;
    int maxBufferSize = 1*1024*1024;
    String urlString = "http://192.168.1.5/upload.php";
    try
    {
        Log.e("MediaPlayer","Inside second Method");
        FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(new File(exsistingFileName) );
        URL url = new URL(urlString);
        conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setDoInput(true);
        // Allow Outputs
        conn.setDoOutput(true);
        // Don't use a cached copy.
        conn.setUseCaches(false);
        // Use a post method.
        conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary="+boundary);
        dos = new DataOutputStream( conn.getOutputStream() );
        dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
        dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uploadedfile\";filename=\"" + exsistingFileName +"\"" + lineEnd);
        dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
        Log.e("MediaPlayer","Headers are written");
        bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
        bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
        buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
        bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
        while (bytesRead > 0)
        {
            dos.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
            bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
            bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
            bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
        }
        dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
        dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
        String inputLine;
        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) 
            tv.append(inputLine);
        // close streams
        Log.e("MediaPlayer","File is written");
        fileInputStream.close();
        dos.flush();
        dos.close();
    }
    catch (MalformedURLException ex)
    {
        Log.e("MediaPlayer", "error: " + ex.getMessage(), ex);
    }
    catch (IOException ioe)
    {
        Log.e("MediaPlayer", "error: " + ioe.getMessage(), ioe);
    }

    //------------------ read the SERVER RESPONSE
    try {
        inStream = new DataInputStream ( conn.getInputStream() );
        String str;            
        while (( str = inStream.readLine()) != null)
        {
            Log.e("MediaPlayer","Server Response"+str);
        }
        /*while((str = inStream.readLine()) !=null ){

        }*/
        inStream.close();
    }
    catch (IOException ioex){
        Log.e("MediaPlayer", "error: " + ioex.getMessage(), ioex);
    }
}
```

Comment: but im import httpclient and httpmime jar